# @Version is not being incremented in Spring mongo

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-mongo

I have added 
@Enableauditng as an annotation but @version is not incrementing the version on its own.
I have @LastModifiedDate, which is being updated but not the @version.

Am i doing somehting wrong.

I am calling mongoTemplate.save(object) to againg and again.

Please advice

Comment: I have to pull back my first answer, you can use org.springframework.data.annotation.Version to annotate a version field. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/1.5.x/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/PersonWithVersionPropertyOfTypeInteger.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are using:

```
javax.persistence.Version
```

Check your imports, @Version is part of javax.persistence (JPA) and has no relation to mongodb.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ 
Unluckily, there is no hint to @Version in the spring data mongodb reference.

You should import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version for entity version information. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/1.5.x/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/PersonWithVersionPropertyOfTypeInteger.java

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "entity" class is a @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document 
and not a
@javax.persistence.Entity

Then, also make sure you're using: 
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
and
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version